# git eclipse always have to pull allready updated project

Tags: eclipse, git, github, version-control

I have this strange behaviour from git, and even if i'll describe it from eclipse egit plugin, from terminal i have the same issue.
I have a project in the workspace that is shared between me and other developers, when i sync the project it says to me that i have to push something like 14/16 commit ant i have to pull one, even if had no commit at all.
Every time that i do the pull it seems that the project is now synchronized, so i push "team syncronize" again and the 14/16 commit to pull appears again.
That's not the only strange thing, another one is that i can push commit to remote after i have pull those commits but the other developers couldn't, even if they do the same things that i've done, it says to them that the problem are a "dangling blob".
Before write some of the solutions that i have found and what i have try i want to say that the number of commits are practically the entire history of the project.
I have tried to use the manual gc of git in the remote repository after i have done an fsck, where i have met effectively two dangling commit (why two dangling commit and egit says one dangling blob? i don't know....), this have removed the two dangling commit, so i have deleted the project from my workspace clone it again, but the same error happens again.
So i have used this other solution http://www.tekkie.ro/news/howto-remove-all-dangling-commits-from-your-git-repository/, always on the remote repository but the problem is still the same.
So even if have read practically all the documentation i didn't undestand somethings:
1) what's the difference between dangling commit and dangling blob?
2) how a dangling commit/blob happens?
3) how can i restore the project's repository?
UPDATE
I start a bounty because i really want to undertand and solve the problem, so for that i'll be clear in what i need to understand:
I have a project that everytime i use team syncronized, want to re-pull all the history, not only to me but for every one ofe my colleague, we use gitblit as remote repos. What can i do? Where do i have to search the possible errors?
UPDATE
that's  **EGIT**
[image]

and that's the **Terminal**
[image]

Comment: Can you run your `git pull` and `git push` commands in a terminal, and add a copy of the output to your question ?

Comment: If i do it from the terminal it seems everything is up-to-date, but when i sync from eclipse it's always give me commit to pull, i'll try to give a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

This is only a answer to some of your issues, maybe it should a comment instead.

Commits and blobs (blobs contains file content) are all objects in the git DAG and an object becomes 'dangling' (unreachable, orphan or loose) when nothing reference it (i.e. not part of the history) and git will clean up dangling objects if you run `git gc` (removes dangling objects older than 2 weeks) and some git commands will also run `git gc --auto` when they are done with their operations.

When you make changes in the DAG (i.e. rebase, amend or re-add content to the index) some objects will be replaced with new ones and the old objects then becomes dangling.

You can run `git fsck --unreachable` to find objects that are dangling.

**Note:** Objects referenced by reflog are normally not considered dangling.

In your case you may need to run `git prune`, `git gc --agressive` or `git gc --prune=now` to remove all dangling objects (do not forget to make a bakup first, just in case)

Comment: I understand you're explanation, and i have try to do all this things, my project still pull and push every commit of his history and i don't understand why. This two dangling commit are my only clue to understand the problem.

Comment: @mautrok, do you get the same result if you pull directly after a push or when only you are pushing to the remote repo? I mean, someone may  do a (forced?) push where they "corupt" the remote repo.

Comment: i get this result always in two conditions:1) when i push  2) when i do the team sync from egit. Another strange behaviour that i noticed today is that if i sync twice consecutively it seems that my project is synced and the arrows desappear, but if sync again the arrows comes again... i don't know anymore where to find the error.